# Baking a pie in air grill / electrical convection oven?

Tags: baking, convection, apple-pie

I got a following device, apparently not too common one. :) Marketed here as air grill, but also named electrical convection oven.

[image: air grill]

It took me a bit of trial and error to learn to cook meat in it (it dries out / overcooks at times meant for normal oven). Once I got that nailed I decided to try baking and results had been total meh. And instruction is of very meh quality and self-contradicting.

### Recipe

Very simple apple pie, popular around here. 4 eggs, glass of sugar, glass of flour, sliced apple. Mix with mixer, pour on apple slices in metal form.

### Attempt 1

30 min at 170C, following "pie with a crust" estimate from instruction.

Was firm on top, but completely liquid inside. Tried to keep more time at 170C, wasn't really doing it, cranked up to 210C and after like hour total of torturing got it more or less baked inside and burnt on top. Obviously with meh result.

### Attempt 2

Cover with foil, 15 min at 210C, then 25 min at 180C, following "if you have trouble baking liquid dough through" in instructions.

Seemed a little more even inside, but still very raw, including on top. Kept for another 20 min at 180C for top to firm up and inside more or less baked. Also very meh.

### Course of action for third attempt?

Any recommendations on time/temperature I should try?

Or should I just give up on baking in it? Marketing here tends to greatly overestimate what device is good for (on paper everything sold is miracle device, replacing rest of the kitchen).

Comment: That looks a awful lot like what is advertised here on late night television as a Flavor Wave. So, I bet this link would be of help to you [Food.com](http://www.food.com/cookbook.php?bookid=173654&ls=o). I'll keep looking for apple pie.

Comment: Here are some more [recipes](https://bestrecipesblog.wordpress.com/tag/flavor-wave-oven/) that look good. Use "Flavor Wave" or "Turbo Oven" in your search strings, I bet you'll find what you need. That's about all the help I can be, since I've never used one. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar device. It was an unused wedding gift that I finally pulled out when my oven door hinge broke...

It does have a tendency to overcook the top before the rest is done. It also seems to cook quite unevenly. The way I get around the uneveness is to rotate the top as it's cooking.

I've baked a few times in it (bread loaves, scones, muffins and quick breads) and haven't really had any disasters but you do need to keep an eye on it.

What you want is to put the item being baked as far away from the element as possible. I always try to cook on the bottom shelf which is fine for things like scones and muffins but bread / quick breads still reach a little high up.

My suggestion is to get an extender ring which pushes up the lid somewhat giving you a greater distance between the heating element and the food, hopefully leading to a more even cook.

I haven't actually tried the extender ring because my version didn't come with one and I haven't had much luck finding one in Australia for a reasonable price.

Comment: Mine cooks very evenly on top, the issue seems to be penetrating thick layer of pie (it's awesome for heating thin pizza for example). I guess disproportionate amount of heat comes from lamp shining on top of food and not hot air circulating around/under the food. I have an extender ring for it, but at the moment my bigger issue seems to be undercooking insides rather than burning top off.